# How to install .sys file into c:\windows\system32\drivers with Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I try to simply install a `.sys` file into

```
Source: "C:\myproject\driver.sys"; DestDir: "{win}\system32\drivers";
```

Once the setup ran, my `driver.sys` is always installed into

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\drivers
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

By default the `{win}\system32` [is redirected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) to `{win}\SysWOW64` by the OS for 32-bit applications (like Inno Setup).

You can override this using [`64bit` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection):

```
Source: "C:\myproject\driver.sys"; DestDir: "{win}\system32\drivers"; Flags: 64bit
```

> **64bit**: Causes the `{sys}` constant to map to the 64-bit System directory when used in the `Source` and `DestDir` parameters, .... This is the default behavior in a [64-bit mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls) install.

---

Or enable [64-bit mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls) install.

```
[Setup]
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64 ia64
```

> In 64-bit mode:
>
> - The System32 path returned by the `{sys}` constant maps to the 64-bit System directory by default when used in the [Dirs], [Files], [InstallDelete], [Run], [UninstallDelete], and [UninstallRun] sections. This is because Setup/Uninstall temporarily disables [WOW64 file system redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) when files/directories are accessed by those sections. Elsewhere, System32 and `{sys}` map to the 32-bit System directory, as is normal in a 32-bit process.

---

As mentioned is all the references above, you should better use [`{sys}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) instead of `{win}\system32`:

```
Source: "C:\myproject\driver.sys"; DestDir: "{sys}\drivers"
```

> **{sys}** The system's System32 directory.
>
> For example: If you used `{sys}\CTL3D32.DLL` on an entry and the system's Windows System directory is "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM", Setup or Uninstall will translate it to "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\CTL3D32.DLL".
>
> On 64-bit Windows, by default, the System32 path returned by this constant maps to the directory containing 32-bit system files, just like on 32-bit Windows. (This can be overridden by enabling [64-bit mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls).)